# Select all the years from a range without having a years table

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, select, recursive-query

I have selected the current year with

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NOW()) as value
```

I want to print a list of all the years from 1990 to the current year without having to create a table of the list of years, is there a way to do it or I must create a table to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select generate_series(1990, (extract(year from now()))::int) as value;
```

or

```
select value from generate_series(1990, (extract(year from now()))::int) as value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive query for this:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select 1990 dt
    union all select dt + 1 from cte where dt < extract(year from now())
)
select dt from cte order by dt
```